# Story of Captain Picard assuming command of the Stargazer

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q, jean-luc-picard

In the TNG episode "Tapestry," Q is talking about the Picard that would never be if Picard had made a different choice in picking a fight with the Nausicaans. One of the events he mentions is the Picard who would “take charge of the Stargazer’s bridge when its captain was killed.”  I know it isn’t mentioned again in the TV series, but is the story of that event detailed in any of the books or comics or other sources?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! Several in fact all by [Michael Jan Friedman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jan_Friedman):

- [Stargazer: Gauntlet](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Gauntlet) (2002)
- [Stargazer: Progenitor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stargazer:_Progenitor) (2002)
- [Stargazer: Three](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stargazer:_Three) (2003)
- [Stargazer: Oblivion](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Oblivion) (2003)
- [Stargazer: Enigma](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Enigma) (2004)
- [Stargazer: Maker](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Maker) (2004)

But it all started with one of the very first TNG novels, also by Michael Jan Friedman, [Star Trek: The Next Generation Reunion](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Reunion_%28novel%29) - in which the remaining crew of the U.S.S. Stargazer reunite to see a former officer installed as ruler of the Daa'Vit Empire.

[image]

> The reunion turns deadly when an assassin begins eliminating Stargazer
>   crew members one by one. Picard's present and former shipmates must
>   join forces to solve the mystery of the assassin who threatens the
>   peace of the entire galaxy.

There are also several other novels and comics that tie-into Picard's past:

- TNG: The Valiant
- TNG Novel 32: Requiem (1997)
- TNG Novel 56: The First Virtue (1999)
- Star Trek: The Next Generation (DC volume 2):

  1. Issue 59: "Children of Chaos"
  2. Issue 60: "Mother of Madness"
  3. Issue 61: "Brothers in Darkness"
- Tales from the Captain's Table: "Darkness" (2005)
- TNG: Death in Winter (2005)
- TNG: The Buried Age (2007)

Comment: To be more precise in answering the question "The Valiant" in particular is the story of how Picard came to command the Stargazer.